# Get current function name of Azure time trigger function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I am trying to access files in the same function folder in a function app time trigger. I am using Powershell code.

How do I access the file

In an HTTP trigger I was able to access the script in the same folder by doing this

> $script_path = ".$($TriggerMetadata.FunctionName)\scriptfile.ps1"

However, this does not work if I am using a time trigger function as the $TriggerMetadata is not being passed when the function is triggered.

I want a way to be able to get the function name of the time trigger dynamically so I can access the script in the same folder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Get the current directory path
$currentPath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

# Construct the file path for your script
$scriptPath = Join-Path -Path $currentPath -ChildPath "scriptfile.ps1"

# Use the $scriptPath to access the file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ***Functions V2***, You can get the function directory via [`$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#psscriptroot) which is documented [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function#powershell-on-functions-v2-or-higher).

> Function context information is
> exposed by the `$TriggerMetadata` variable in the run.ps1 file. This
> variable contains the function name, directory, and invocation id. ***If
> you are using a template that does not have the `$TriggerMetadata`
> variable, you can get function directory via `$PSScriptRoot`***. See
> example below:
>
> ```
> using namespace System.Net
>
> # Input bindings are passed in via param block.
> param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
>
> # Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
> Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."
>
> write-output "Current directory:"
> write-output "PSScriptRoot: $PSScriptRoot"
> write-output "Directory: $($TriggerMetadata.FunctionDirectory)"
>
> write-output "FunctionName: $($TriggerMetadata.FunctionName)"
> write-output "InvocationId: $($TriggerMetadata.InvocationId)"
>
> # more code ...
> ```

For ***Functions V1***, You can use the [`EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONDIRECTORY` environment variable](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function#v1-experimental-languages-powershell-php-python-bash-batch-and-other-scripting-languages) to access the function directory.

| Property name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONDIRECTORY | Provides the current function directory (e.g. when running on Azure, d:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1) |

```
$functionDir = $env:EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONDIRECTORY
Write-Host $functionDir
```